# ajax() considering value null jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get all input data from a `div` and send it for processing (in PHP). However, even though I am certain, as I have console logged the variable `bookeeDetails` before calling the `ajax()` function, there is a value.

```
$("#finalsubmit").click(function () {
    var bookeeDetails = [];

    $("#bookeeDetails :input").each(function () {
        bookeeDetails[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });

    console.log(bookeeDetails);

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            bookee: bookeeDetails
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $("#info").html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Basically, I'm going for having access to `$_POST['bookee']['keyname']` in the PHP script. Unfortunately, when the request is being sent nothing is being received in PHP. I have tested putting in fixed values, and that works, and I am 100% certain `bookeeDetails` contains data.

Is this a case of `bookeeDetails` not being populated yet as the request is being sent before the populating loop completes? If so, how do I stop this from happening?

Comment: `bookeeDetails[$(this).attr('name')]` that's wrong - you're treating an _array_ as if it's an _object_. In PHP that is fine, but not in JavaScript. I don't know if this is your problem but it certainly won't help.

Comment: try to serialize your array , but i think you should construct a json value instead array to send ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since i see submit in `finalsubmit` i guess that you've a form there so probably you're looking for **[`serializeArray`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)**:

```
$( '#bookeeDetails' ).serializeArray();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var data = $( '#bookeeDetails' ).serializeArray();

var books = {};

$.each(data, function(i, obj){
  books[obj.name] = obj.value;  
})

console.log(books);
console.log(books['title']);
console.log(books['autor']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id='bookeeDetails'>
  <input type="text" name="title" value="Biography">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="autor" value="Jack">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="edition" value="2016">
</form>
```

Comment: I actually tried this first, but I end up with an unnecessary dimension; i.e. to get the title, for example, it's `$_POST['bookee'][0]['value']`, but the point is that I want to be able to refer to the data via key reference (something more like `$_POST['bookee']['title']`). Basically, this is what `serializeArray()` gives me:

Comment: @A.Appleby you can easily massage the data of `$.serializeArray` by doing `.map().reduce()` (or a straight `reduce` combining both operations)

Comment: This is what I want:

Comment: array(1) {
    ['bookee']=>
        array(9) {
            [0]=>
  array(2) {
             ['name']=>'title',
             ['value']=>'Mr'
  }
            [1]=>
                array(2) {
                    ['name']=>'first_name',
                    ['value]=>'Alastair'
                }
 }
}